# How can I use wildcards with \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, pdf, include, paths, includegraphics

I would like to use `\includegraphics{folder/*.pdf}` in this simple way, I've got a folder inside which I have different files and I want to pick only the pdf one. Is this possible ?

Comment: “The” PDF one? Will there be just one?

Comment: yes, in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a Unix system:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\includegraphicsfromfolder}{O{}mm}
 {% #1 = options, #2 = folder path, #3 = extension
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { ls~-m~#2/* } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { , } \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \regex_match:nnT { \.#3\Z } { ##1 }
     {
      \includegraphics[#1]{##1}
      \seq_map_break:
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\includegraphicsfromfolder[width=4cm]{folder}{pdf}

\includegraphicsfromfolder[height=2cm]{folder}{png}

\end{document}
```

This requires the `-shell-escape` option.

We get a `ls` from the given folder, with entries separated by commas; then the list is split at commas and each entry is tested to end with the required extension; in the case of success, the image is included and the mapping is stopped.

It could be possible to add code for ensuring that some warning is issued if no suitable image is found.

[image]

The `folder` subdirectory for the example contains

```
> ls folder
example-image-a.png example-image.pdf
```